# How can I dynamically change the port in a script's source attribute based on the current domain in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

MOTIVATION

- Trying to move static sources from tomcat-server to apache-server.

SETUP

- I have a running apache-server at port 9443; there, I am serving static files with cross domain request (Cors) allowed.
- I have a running tomcat server at port 8443; there are multiple web-applications running.

QUESTION

- I want to dynamically adjust the port in the `<script>` tag's `src` attribute based on the current domain, without hardcoding the domain.

EXAMPLE-FILES
JS file served by Apache at port 9443:

- URL: `https://localhost:9443/app-common/index.js`
- Responsibilities:

  - add fonts, 'js'es, 'css's
  - If web app is GWT app, starts it
- Contents:

```js
//simplified...

window.includeIFrame = function(src, id, width, height, border) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", src);
    if (id !== null)
        iframe.setAttribute("id", id);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    if (width !== null)
        iframe.style.width = width;
    if (height !== null)
        iframe.style.height = height;
    if (border !== null)
        iframe.style.border = border;
};

window.includeJS = function(filepath) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = filepath;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
};


window.gwt_utils_initialize = function() {
    window.includeIFrame("javascript:''", "__gwt_historyFrame", "0px", "0px", "0px");
    window.includeJS("app/app.nocache.js?r=" + Math.random());
};

if (typeof window.boot_loader_main === 'undefined') {
    window.boot_loader_main = function() {
        window.gwt_utils_initialize();
    };
};

window.boot_loader_main();

//...
```

HTML page served by Tomcat at port 8443:

- URL: `https://localhost:8443/app-name1/index.jsp`
- Contents:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">
    <script src="../app-common/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

SUMMARY

- I need a way to adjust the port in the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag so that it points to the correct location of `index.js` without explicitly specifying the domain or port.
- I know HTML is a static language; how can I achieve this dynamically, using JavaScript?

Comment: _"Is it possible to change the port on the 'src' parameter, without knowing the domain name?"_ - in a _static_ way, you mean; not by _setting_ the `src` dynamically _using_ code? No, that is not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change script "src" by URL param and make it functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572333/change-script-src-by-url-param-and-make-it-functional)

Comment: `var url = new URL(document.querySelector('script').src); url.port = 9443; document.querySelector('script').src = url.toString();`

Comment: `As js file is common for all the webapps I have, I want to move the js file apache server on port 9443` that's going to make the  script source a cross-source request subject to CORS.  So you'll have to set that up too.

Comment: Did the suggested duplicate help?  If not, it's probably useful to explain why not in the question, or at least here in the comments.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds there was an answer here, then it disappered. Let me wrote how I did according to that answer...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds the proposed duplicate is related to parameters inside url. On thsi question, url has no parameters.

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak Thanks for the feedback on that.  I didn't feel that I could vote-to-reopen with a possible duplicate outstanding.  As for the deleted answer, I can see it, since I have enough Rep, and it was deleted by a Moderator, almost certainly because it was [AI-generated content](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  I'm glad you got what you needed and were able to make it work.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds For the moment,  I wish the answer stays there, so people can benefit. If the question re-opens, I am planning to do that.

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak Reopened - Post away ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use 'window.location' to fetch current protocol and hostname.
Here is the implementation I am using.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <script>
            //GLOBAL VARS
            let protocol = window.location.protocol.substring(0, window.location.protocol.length-1);
                console.log(protocol);
            let hostname = window.location.hostname;
                console.log(hostname);
            let port = 9443;
                console.log(port);
            let path = "app-common/index.js";
                console.log(path);
            {//INDEX JS SCRIPT
                let src =  protocol + '://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/' + path;
                console.log(src);
                let script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = src;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As a bonus, the global variables (protocol,hostname,port) can also be used inside 'index.js' file when including other JS and CSS files.